# How to capitalize first letter of each word in the string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

How to capitalize first letter of each world in the string in Ruby on Rails:

```
"goyette-xyz-is wide road".titleize returns "Goyette Xyz Is Wide Road".
```

I want the output like:

```
"goyette-xyz is wide road".SOME-FUNCTION should return "Goyette-xyz-is Wide Road".
```

titleize removes the underscore and hyphens but i want to keep it in the string.

Comment: `"goyette-xyz-is wide road".split(' ').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')`

Comment: How should a computer know that `Goyette`, `Wide`, and `Road` are words that should be capitalized, and `xyz` and `is` are not? Are you planning to have a database or artificial intelligence as part of this method? Tell us what kind of AI you are using. Otherwise, the question is not fully stated.

Comment: @sawa I think the OP wants to treat the hyphenated part (`goyette-xyz-is`) as one word.

Comment: @Stefan I don't get why a hyphen is added in the result between `"goyette-xyz"` and `"is"`. That is another point that the question is not clear.

Comment: Didn't see that, but it looks like a typo to me. The first line has that hyphen.

Answer (score 47):

you can just use the `.titleize`   like this `"i want to make the first letter of each work into a cap".titleize`

you can learn more about [titleize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/titleize) from the apidocks

titleize(word) public

Capitalizes all the words and replaces some characters in the string to create a nicer looking title. titleize is meant for creating pretty output. It is not used in the Rails internals.

titleize is also aliased as as titlecase.

Examples:

```
"man from the boondocks".titleize   # => "Man From The Boondocks"
"x-men: the last stand".titleize    # => "X Men: The Last Stand"
"TheManWithoutAPast".titleize       # => "The Man Without A Past"
"raiders_of_the_lost_ark".titleize  # => "Raiders Of The Lost Ark"
```

how this actuality works

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb, line 115
def titleize(word)
  humanize(underscore(word)).gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
end
```

---

To Actually keep in "-" in the works we can add a new method to the string class like this.

```
# ./lib/core_ext/string.rb
class String
  #"goyette-xyz-is wide road".titleize_with_dashes#=> "Goyette-xyz-is Wide Road"
  def titleize_with_dashes
    humanize.gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize }
  end
end
```

Comment: Though nicely explaining how titleize works it doesn't actually answer the question : how to titleize while keeping dashes.

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question.

Comment: @DanishM. I just added a update to my solution, I hope that his helps

Answer (score 6):

You could implement proper method by yourself:

```
class String
  def my_titleize
    split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  end
end

"goyette-xyz-is wide road".my_titleize
#=> "Goyette-xyz-is Wide Road"
```

Comment: @apneadiving why not? rails got hold bunch of them https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/feaa6e2048fe86bcf07e967d6e47b865e42e055b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext

Comment: @j03w Rails core developers have a great knowledge of Ruby. Actually Rails conventions are almost part of what Rails developers expect from Ruby itself. When you work with Rails it's part of the foundations, if you want to play with foudnations, have fun but fear for your stability

Answer (score 2):

And if like for me right now you need to capitalize the first letter even for dashed words, you can do it like this:

```
def titleize_and_keep_dashes(text)
  text.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ').split('-').map(&:titleize).join('-')
end
titleize_and_keep_dashes("goyette-xyz-is wide road")
# => "Goyette-Xyz Is Wide Road".
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `.capitalize` method to your String to get the First letter capitalized automatically.